# C++ vector insertion sort algorithm method - pass vector into method

Tags: c++, vector, insertion-sort

Ive look everywhere and whatever algorithm I find (if any lol) for insertion sort on a vector in c++, it wont work so im assuming it has something to do with my code. Can anyone help me find a way I can pass a vector into a method as an argument and then do an insertion sort on it? At the moment it waits for a few seconds and shows all the values unsorted :(

Insertion Sort Code

```
void insertionSort (vector<int> data, int n) 
{
int i, j, tmp;

 for (i=1; i<n; i++)
 {
     j=i;
     tmp=data[i];
     while (j>0 && tmp<data[j-1])
     {
           data[j]=data[j-1];
           j--;
     }
     data[j]=tmp;
 }
```

The important part of the code

```
        cout << "insertion sort" << endl;
        system("pause");
        insertionSort(numberVectors, i);
```

let me know if you dont think theres anything wrong with that code and you want me to show you more, should just be this bit though, the other stuff is irrelavent i think

thanks

Comment: Best is to make your function a template.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your function accepts its argument by value; this means it gets a *copy*. You sort the copy, in vain.

Change it to a reference instead:

```
void insertionSort (vector<int>& data, int n)
```

Comment: everything I do...theres always a simple solution, thank you ever so much, very grateful, can carry on now, this was buggin me for ages :)

Comment: Also, if `n` is just the number of elements in `data` then you don't even need it, since you can call `data.size()` to find out how many elements there are.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your array by reference, then changes in the function will be reflected on it

```
void insertionSort (vector<int> &data, int n) 
{
   ...
}
```