# Fill vector with unrepeated random numbers. why not working?

Tags: c++

I've seen the approaches for creating a vector of unrepeated random numbers based on `std::random_shuffle`, however I need to implement an alternative approach. This is my code:

```
std::vector<int> create_unrepeated_random(int v_size, int v_max) {

  // Max index value must be grater than the number of vector size
  assert(v_max > v_size);

  std::vector<int> ret;

  int val = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < v_size; i++) {

    val = std::rand() % v_max; 

    // Keep generating new values until we generate one that is not already in  
    // output vector
    if (ret.size() > 0) {
      while (!std::binary_search(ret.begin(), ret.end(), val)) {
        val = std::rand() % v_max; 
      }
    }

    ret.push_back(val);

  }


  assert ((int)ret.size() == v_size);
  for (auto &v: ret) printf("%d ", v);printf("\n");

  return ret;

}
```

However, this is not working, don't know why. Some numbers appear repated sometimes.

BUT if I change the `while` loop to

```
 while (std::binary_search(ret.begin(), ret.end(), val))
```

this creates a vector of repeated random numbers. What is wrong here?

Comment: Looks to me like you are using a binary search, which requires a sorted list, on a list that is not sorted. As you generate new numbers which are not in the list, you should do an insertion sort so that the numbers in the list will remain sorted.

Comment: See [how do you insert the value in a sorted vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843525/how-do-you-insert-the-value-in-a-sorted-vector) for a discussion as well as [C++ vector insertion sort algorithm method - pass vector into method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709637/c-vector-insertion-sort-algorithm-method-pass-vector-into-method).

Comment: As an improvement, you can change the `vector` declaration to `std::vector<int> ret(v_size);`

Comment: Just a suggestion to make your code more readable you can change this if (ret.size() > 0) to this if(!ret.empty() ) It will essentially do the same as vector::size() will return an unsigned int. Sorry was small typo, re-posting comment :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::binary_search
```

only works on sorted ranges. Use `std::find` instead:

```
while (std::find(ret.begin(), ret.end(), val) != ret.end())
```

Alternatively, you may use `std::unordered_set`:

```
std::unordered_set<int> ret;
while (ret.size() < v_size) {
    ret.insert(rand() % v_max);
}
```

Keep in mind that with this approach the order of the generated number will be unspecified, i.e. probably less random than the vector approach. If you want a sorted sequence of random numbers, consider `std::set`.

---

Remark: The use of `rand()` is discouraged in modern C++, although it will probably do the trick for toy programs. See also https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful